# Fail to receive WhatsApp messages from a specific contact

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am not able to receive WhatsApp messages from a specific contact while I am able to send them messages.

All other contacts appear to be receiving and having no issues with the sending process. I also don't block the contact.

What's the possible cause? How to fix this, or any workaround?

Comment: Besides the contact being [blocked](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/21080506), have you checked if the contact is properly [inserted](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/21082107/)? _(check my links)_

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I had a very symilar problem with a contact today.
Creating a group with only the problematic contact was a successful workaround, the final solution was deleting the original chat that stopped working and creating a new one.